# Does loading Google Analytics script with RequireJS affect tracking metrics?

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, web, google-analytics, requirejs

I would like to know if loading the Google Analytics script with RequireJS affects tracking metrics such as page load times, etc.

Here are some resources on the topic that I have found:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/17607058

https://stackoverflow.com/a/18280750

http://veithen.github.io/2015/02/14/requirejs-google-analytics.html

https://dzone.com/articles/requirejs-and-google-analytics

The resources above do not address the topic of tracking metrics directly.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It does not. `analytics.js` page load time data is derived from the [Navigation Timing API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Navigation_timing_API), which means it's not affected by when or how the script is loaded. The timing data is coming from the browser itself.

The only way metrics could be affected by how the script is loaded is for visitors that leave the page immediately. If a visitor leaves before the `analytics.js` script can load (and thus send data back to GA), then those visits will not be counted. But for things like page load time, that data source is fixed and will not be affected by the script load mechanism.